# comparaison: 'like' or 'as'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, as-like

I'm writing a fantasy story, and I have this sentence edited by different persons in different ways. I want to play with the word 'present' and 'gift', meaning 'the present' (no past, no future) is also a gift we should be conscious about. Thank you for your help!
A) Time is no longer time as I thought; no past, no future, just the present. Yes, that's it, the present **like** a gift. 
B) Time is no longer time as I thought; no past, no future, just the present. Yes, that's it, the present **as** a gift.

Comment: There can be difference between *like* (similar to) and *as* (used in the way of) here, but that difference is only there if it's interpreted that way, and it's not enough of a difference to clearly indicate one use over the other.

Comment: Patricia, to me, the clause "Yes, that's it" is used to reinforce a previously stated idea, but it is being used to join together two *different* ideas ("Time is only the present" and "the present is a gift"). Perhaps you could consider saying "... just the present. The present **is** a gift." if the character is speaking in a stream of consciousness that they will expand on, or "... just the present. The present **as** a gift." I agree that there's no large difference here between "like" or "as".

Comment: Thank you, CMoney. I want to show the parallel meaning between 'present' and 'gift,' so I think I'll keep the option B.